# Broken Insert id of new rows

Tags: android, sqlite, sequence, android-room

I'm using Room. 
I have this insert method:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insert(Month month);
```

My insert method:

```
for(...){
...
monthDao.insert(new Month(0, monthTitle, monthUrl));
}
```

Also my model

```
@Entity(tableName = "news_month_table", indices = @Index(value = {"month_index"}, unique = true))
public class Month {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = "month_id")
@Getter @Setter
public long month_id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "month_name")
@Getter @Setter
public String monthName;
@ColumnInfo(name = "month_url")
@Getter @Setter
public String monthURL;
@ColumnInfo(name = "month_index")
@Getter @Setter
public int monthIndex;
```

My situation:
1) Launch the app and download+insert data (12 rounds of for())
Now base is correct and contains 12 rows with 1-12 id's.
2) I have new data(ex for one row). Launch the app and download+insert data.
Now base contains 13 rows with 1-12 and 24 id.

I dont know what is problem, help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert new elements by this code:

```
MonthDao.insert(new Month(monthDao.getLastMonthId()+1, monthTitle, monthUrl, mIndex));
```

...

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM news_month_table ORDER BY month_id DESC LIMIT 1;")
int getLastMonthId();
```

Just the way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem regards the unique index on monthIndex attribute. Please check how you set the value of this attribute. Check on your database the value of associated column.